# I don' t understand the retriving value syntax

Tags: python, numpy

Here i have the shape of my set

```
input [8] : train_x.shape

Out [8] : (4500, 3, 2)
```

Then in don't understand the following syntax

```
input [9] : train_x_retrive = train_x[:, -1, :]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: @FredLarson It probably won't. The slicing operations in the questions are not basic python, they are slicing on multidimensional array (ndarray) defined in numpy.

Answer (score 1):

See,
`(4500, 3, 2)` means 3 dimension data
with 1st dimension having 4500 length, 2nd dimension having 3 length and 3rd dimension having 2 length.

What `train_x[:, -1, :]` Means is that retrieve all the data of first dimension, of the last data of 2nd dimension of all the 3rd dimension.

results shape will be `(4500, 2)`

--EDIT--

Turns out if the returned array has only one selection then there is no need to display it, and so np automatically squeeze that column. so instead of getting array of size (4500,1,2) it returns (4500,2)

Comment: "1st dimension having 4500 data, 2nd dimension having 3 data and 3rd dimension having 2 data." -> No. It's "1st dimension's length is 4500, 2nd dimension's length is 3 and 3rd dimension's length is 2."

Comment: I think the result would be of shape (4500, 2). It usually squeezes the single selection.

Comment: @Jona Edited the terminology

Comment: @Ehsan You are right, it squeeze the single row. Edited my ans. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the squeezing in you answer ? When I read it, it is not obvious to me.

Comment: Turns out if the returned array has only one selection then there is no need to display it, and so np automatically squeeze that column. so instead of getting array of size (4500,1,2) it returns (4500,2).

Comment: Why not put this in the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

While @thisisjaymehta 's answer is correct and well explained, I find it is much easier to understand what's happening in a 2D array.

Consider a 3 row, 2 col random array:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.random((3,2))
print(X)
```

Yields:

```
array([[0.05809464, 0.49751321],
       [0.25815324, 0.23862334],
       [0.56815427, 0.91610693]])
```

We can access individual elements with subscripting. For instance to reach row (horizontal) 0, col (vertical) 1 we can use `X[0,1]`:

```
print(X[0,1])
```

Which yields:

```
0.49751320772009267
```

Similarly we can reach the last row, and the first (0th) column by using `X[-1,0]`:

```
0.568154265734957
```

The notation `:` is used to address the whole of that axis, so to get the last row, and all of the columns in that last row we can use `X[-1,:]` to yeild:

```
array([0.56815427, 0.91610693])
```

This principle extends in 3 or more dimensions as well. So `train_x[:, -1, :]` means "All rows (first dimension), the last column (second dimension), and all of the third dimension". This results in an array of shape `(4500,2)` in your example, where you started with `(4500, 3, 2)`.

The way I like to think of this is you have `4500` `3x2` images, and you are requesting for the last row of each image. The resultant array contains `4500` `1,2` image strips, squeezed into a `4500,2` array.

You could also do `-2` in place of `-1` to reach the penultimate index.